# how to completely uninstall flutter on macos and reinstall it in the correct way?

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-development

I'm  facing an issue when installing flutter on my macOs BigSur as I have set the flutter path the wrong way and I have messed everything up.

I just want a way to completely uninstall flutter and re-install it the right way.

```
ro:~ yahyasaleh$ which flutter
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ 
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ flutter docker
-bash: flutter: command not found
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$  echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:[/Users/yahyasaleh/Developer/flutter/bin]/flutter/bin
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ git clean -xfd
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ git stash save --keep-index
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ git stash drop
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ git pull
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ flutter doctor
-bash: flutter: command not found
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ rm -rf
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ which flutter
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$ git clean -xfd
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
YAHYAs-MacBook-Pro:~ yahyasaleh$
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is an SDK that you download and unpack onto a directory in your Mac. There is no automatic uninstall process in the same way that there is no automatic install process. You "installed" it by downloading a zip file and unzipping it. All you have to do is remove the contents of the directory where you unzipped it in.

Even the path addition to be able to call the flutter command from anywhere in your system has to be done manually. If you did that, then you can remove it as well from your shell's PATH.

you could rm -rf the sdk folder, or if you just want to clean a corrupt run the following commands in the Flutter install directory:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```